# Problems with including custom c++ library in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I was trying to include the GMP library, which was simply the code below(I did nothing else):

```
#include <gmpxx.h>
```

However, when I tried to compile the code, the following error from g++ compiler occured:

```
myCode.cpp:3:10: fatal error: gmpxx.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gmpxx.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have tried everything I searched online, putting the GMP lib here and there, adding INFINITE includepaths in c_cpp_properties.json, still, it keeps showing the message, although, I can find the file through "Go to Definition" option.

Is there any known solution to this?

Comment: What's your compile command?

Comment: `g++ myCode.cpp` ,if that is what you're talking about.

Comment: Please see here: https://gmplib.org/manual/Headers-and-Libraries.html

Comment: In essence try: `g++ mycxxprog.cc -lgmpxx -lgmp`

Comment: Ok so reading through the document I realized I install it in the "non-standard" loaction, it said I need to use "-I" and "-L" compiler options. Can anyone explain me what those are?

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to configure VS Code includes, you need to pass those options to the compiler as well.

You don't mention your platform at all, so I'm going to use an example from my personal machine, a Macbook Pro with the fmt library.

When compiling with the fmt library, I have to provide three more options to the compiler.

```
-I/usr/local/include  // Tells the compiler where to look for extra includes
-L/usr/local/lib      // Tells the compiler where to look for extra libraries
-lfmt                 // fmt-specific command to use fmt library
```

So the full command ends up looking like this:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++17 -I/user/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lfmt main.cpp
```

I need all three options because fmt is installed in a non-standard location that the compiler doesn't check by default. According to [the documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Headers-and-Libraries.html), you can get away with just `-lgmp` and `-lgmpxx` if you installed the library in a standard location (happens by default with *nix and a package manager, I imagine).

If you use build tasks in VS Code, this can be set up and automated for you.